# Is it possible to create zalgo text with emojis?

Tags: unicode, emoji, zalgo

Not only the base character, but also the messed up gibberish. I know Zalgo text is created from combining Unicode characters, and as emojis are Unicode characters, this thought came in my mind.

Answer (score 6):

Zalgo text (ab)uses a very *specific* subset of Unicode characters: [combining diacritics](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/list.htm). A combining diacritic character is an accent that should appear above or below (or through, although that is rather rare) the preceding character. Because some scripts demand more than one accent "stacked" on top of the previous one, these characters also stack on top of themselves. That is how you create Zalgo text: by stacking loads and loads of diacritics on top of each other.

So that is a definitive "no", because emoji are not dicacritic characters and so they carry no information on how they should be stacked.

For fun, let's test if you *can* add diacritics *to* emoji:

> before:
>
> after:
>
> ̩̲̜̱͓̟͙ͮͦ̿ͦ̐́̌̀҉̷̖͙̤͓̯̮͂̓̿̿̇͊͋̎ͤ̒ͥ̓̈

<sup>Note that both visibility and accurate rendering may be influenced by your broswer.</sup>